# Firebase database create node with user id under users node

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to push a node with created user's uid or localId in firebase database instead of using idToken. But i am geting an error in doing so. I want to know if it is possible or not?
If not what can i do to authenticate that the user is registered with us.

```
`firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(configS)

auth = firebase.auth()
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("sourabh.iit@gmail.com","sourabh")
db = firebase.database()
uid=user['localId']
data = dict(
    name= "sourabh",
    phone= "9898799899",
    id= uid
)
results = db.child("users").push(data,'sourabh')

print(results)`
```

error i am getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/abhimanyu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py",
>   line 444, in raise_detailed_error
>       request_object.raise_for_status()   File "/home/abhimanyu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/models.py",
>   line 862, in raise_for_status
>       raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:
>   https://sourabh-64c73.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=sourabh
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "firebasetest.py", line 27,
>   in 
>       results = db.child("users").push(data,'sourabh')   File "/home/abhimanyu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py",
>   line 293, in push
>       raise_detailed_error(request_object)   File "/home/abhimanyu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyrebase/pyrebase.py",
>   line 448, in raise_detailed_error
>       raise HTTPError(e, request_object.text) requests.exceptions.HTTPError: [Errno 401 Client Error: Unauthorized
>   for url: https://sourabh-64c73.firebaseio.com/users.json?auth=sourabh]
>   {   "error" : "Could not parse auth token." }

Comment: Please refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write 
It explains what you are expecting. You can find same concept for iOS and Web in side menu.

Comment: No, it is not there. I read somewhere that database secret is needed but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Please provide the code and the error output, otherwise there's nothing to diagnose here.